# Unable to retrieve correct values from rest api (RetroFit)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to post a request via a JSON body through Retrofit2 in Android.
I am trying to hit api at https://magicspree.com/restaurant/webservice/android/login.
Here is my code.`

Input json body (requests via POST method):

```
{
 "restaurantapikey":"v4Vk2wEkzZfWGxeChavYKLnamLrXaDUJTpiInqeU",
 "restaurantusername":"dvar.rddwarka.del",
 "restaurantpassword":"password"
}
```

Restaurant.java(model class):

```
public class Restaurant {
  @SerializedName("restaurantApiKey")
  private String restaurantApiKey;
  @SerializedName("restaurantUserName")
  private String restaurantUserName;
  @SerializedName("restaurantPassword")
  private String restaurantPassword;
  @SerializedName("Status")
  @Expose
  private String status;
  @SerializedName("Text")
  @Expose
  private String text;
  @SerializedName("Restaurant_id")
  @Expose
  private Integer restaurantId;
  public String getRestaurantApiKey() {
     return restaurantApiKey;
  }
  public void setRestaurantApiKey(String restaurantApiKey) {
     this.restaurantApiKey = restaurantApiKey;
  }
  public String getRestaurantUserName() {
     return restaurantUserName;
  }
  public void setRestaurantUserName(String restaurantUserName) {
     this.restaurantUserName = restaurantUserName;
  }
  public String getRestaurantPassword() {
     return restaurantPassword;
  }
  public void setRestaurantPassword(String restaurantPassword) {
     this.restaurantPassword = restaurantPassword;
  }
  public Restaurant(String apiKey, String userName,String password) {
     this.restaurantApiKey = apiKey;
     this.restaurantUserName = userName;
     this.restaurantPassword=password;
  }
  public String getStatus() {
     return status;
  }
  public void setStatus(String status) {
     this.status = status;
  }
  public String getText() {
     return text;
  }
  public void setText(String text) {
     this.text = text;
  }
  public Integer getRestaurantId() {
     return restaurantId;
  }
  public void setRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId) {
     this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
  }
  public String toString(){
     return "id="+restaurantId+", status="+getStatus()+", text="+getText();
  }
}
```

ApiClient.java:

```
public class ApiClient {
 public static final String BASE_URL = 
 "https://magicspree.com/restaurant/webservice/android/";
 private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
 public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

ApiInterface.java:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
 @POST("login")
 Call<Restaurant> loginRestaurant(@Body Restaurant restaurant);
}
```

My onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
Restaurant r=new Restaurant("v4Vk2wEkzZfWGxeChavYKLnamLrXaDUJTpiInqeU","dvar.rddwarka.del","password");

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Restaurant> call = apiService.loginRestaurant(r);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Restaurant>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Restaurant> call2, Response<Restaurant> response) {
            System.out.println(response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Restaurant> call, Throwable t) {

        }
});
}
```

Expected output JSON:

```
{"Status":"Success","Text":"Login Successful","Restaurant_id":27}
```

The problem is that I am getting the values as Status:Failed, Text:Null, and Restaurant_id:0. I have just started with Retrofit so I do not understand it properly. Please tell me how to retrieve the expected values correctly.

Comment: I would suggest you hide your API key and username and password :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be naive but with my eagle eyes :) I see that in Postman your parameter is all in lower case while in your code it is Camel case (restaurantapikey 
 vs restaurantApiKey )
It might be your backend is implemented with case sensitive parameter.
Change your Restaurant class to use this :

```
@SerializedName("restaurantapikey")
private String restaurantApiKey;
@SerializedName("restaurantusername")
private String restaurantUserName;
@SerializedName("restaurantpassword")
private String restaurantPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually I had used lower case params in code as well, just typed it wrong into Stack Overflow :P Anyways I just changed my endpoints to everything after the first slash in the url and used "@field" instead of "@body" and now its working. Thanks anyway :)